# When resizing a window in Ubuntu, the spot is too small for my mouse to find

Tags: mouse, desktop, window

When I want to resize a window in Ubuntu, I put my mouse cursor near the edge of the window and I have to slow down and hunt for the exact right pixel when the mouse cursor turns into the that left-right-arrow so I can resize the window.

Is there some way to make this "resizable" area larger, so I don't have to spend so much time slowing down to find it?

(Mint is really nice.  How can I make Ubuntu more like Mint in this regard?)

Thanks.

Comment: Mint is just Ubuntu and some extras, but is also more bloated. 
It does look like you've just landed into Linux. If you installed the very latest version of Ubuntu (20.10), do note that you'll soon or later get troubles since it's more of a Beta for what are called Ubuntu "LTS" (the real stable versions), do prefer and (re)install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instead. Then, only upgrade it with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS when it comes, and skip any intermediate/beta versions (e.g 20.10, 21.04 and 21.10). Also, do install the `synaptic` package first things first, since any `apt-get install` can be done on that GUI

Comment: , except for `apt-get install synaptic` that is.
Same goes for your system updates (called "upgrades" in Linux), no need for `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, we're not in the 80ies anymore :).
Do note that going to a newer Ubuntu version is called `dist-upgrade`.
I don't have an answer for your question, but it looks like you already want to get rid of the default Ubuntu GUI, which is called Gnome 3 (tablet/macos GUI clone). You can have the same GUI as Mint that is called Cinnamon, which can be installed on Ubuntu with the `cinnamon` package, though `synaptic` of course (5 clicks).